# Converting a json string to a public ulong

Tags: c#, discord.net

I need to use a string from a json file as an ulong, and then use that varialble in a different class. I tried parsing it to be a uint, but the public ulong is then said to be unused, even though it seems as if it's being used to me. This might be super obvious but I'm new to c#.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MinecraftClient
{
    class Utilities
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> whitelisted;

        static Utilities()
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("whitelists/walls.json");
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            whitelisted = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        }

        public static ulong GetWhitelisted(string key)
        {
            if (whitelisted.ContainsKey(MinecraftClient.ChatBots.WeeWoo.username))
            {
                ulong whitelistedid;
                bool parsed = UInt64.TryParse(key, out whitelistedid);
            }
            return 0;

        }
        public static ulong whitelistedid;
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re setting a local variable `whitelistedid` but not assigning that value to the public property with the same name..

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `if` block you are declaring a new variable named `whitelistedid` (and you're creating a variable named `parsed`), but they are never used and the method always returns `0`.

Instead you probably want to do something like:

```
public static ulong GetWhitelisted(string key)
{
    if (whitelisted.ContainsKey(MinecraftClient.ChatBots.WeeWoo.username))
    {
        ulong userWhiteListId;

        if (UInt64.TryParse(key, out userWhiteListId))
        {
            // If parsing succeeded, return the value
            return userWhiteListId;
        }

        // Optionally, return some other value if the user was found but parsing failed
        // return -1;
    }

    // Either the user wasn't found or the parsing failed
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that rather than having a public static variable you actually just want to return the ulong from your static method.  Probably something more like...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MinecraftClient
{
    class Utilities
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> whitelisted;

        static Utilities()
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText("whitelists/walls.json");
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            whitelisted = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        }

        public static ulong GetWhitelisted(string key)
        {
            if (whitelisted.ContainsKey(MinecraftClient.ChatBots.WeeWoo.username))
            {
                ulong parsedId;
                if (UInt64.TryParse(key, out parsedId))
                    return parsedId;                    
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to get your whitelist you would do...

```
var whileListId = Utilities.GetWhiteListed("someKey");
```